# WPF no "View Designer" context menu[visual studio]

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2022, xaml-designer

Visual Studio 2022 17.1.1

In the previous version, right-clicking in the xx.XAML.cs file could see the menu "View Designer",
But now sometimes I can't find it
[image: Visual Studio 2022]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Visual Studio 2022. See here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Designer-Cannot-Open-file/1505106?space=8&q=The+Designer+could+not+be+shown+for+this+file+because+none+of+the+classes+within+it+can+be+designed

Also refer to the final reactions after the feedback bot closed the issue - there are some added things that people are advised to check that might be causing this.

P.S There are still people reporting issues with the designer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-WPF-designer-crashes/1688185?space=8&q=%5BVisual+Studio+2022+version+17.1%5D+designer&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem&sort=votes